# Utilizar duas entitades na mesma View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Possuo uma tabela, onde me retorna os registros de férias de cada funcionário, e preciso criar uma página, onde o usuário possa requirir a alteração desse período. Porém, a demanda solicita que os dados fique na mesma "tabela". Sendo assim, preciso fazer um foreach na tabela férias, e colocar os campos de alteração(tabela requerimento) na mesma view.

Essa imagem exemplifica o resultado final que preciso obter.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso, a Data Inicio e a Data Fim pertence a classe férias, e o restante a classe requerimento. 
Minha demanda é que ao usuário clicar em editar, a tabela habilite os campos Data inicial alteração e data final alteração, para o usuário colocar as datas que deseje, e assim eu salve esses dados no banco de dados, na tabela requerimento.

No banco de dados, eu retorno os dados "Data Inicio e Data Fim" de uma View, chamada Férias, e os dados "Data Inicial Alteração e Data Final Alteração" devem ser salvos em uma tabela chamada Requerimentos.

Não sei como consigo fazer isso, se uso ViewModel, javascript, Jquery, etc.

Método para salvar:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Ferias(Requerimento requerimento)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    requerimento.sLotacao = SessionHelper.Lotacao;
                    requerimento.sNome = SessionHelper.Nome;
                    if (SessionHelper.Celular == null || SessionHelper.Celular == " ")
                    {
                        requerimento.sTelefone = SessionHelper.Telefone;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        requerimento.sCelular = SessionHelper.Celular;
                    }

                    requerimento.sEndereco = SessionHelper.Endereco;
                    requerimento.sEmail = SessionHelper.Email;
                    requerimento.sVinculo = SessionHelper.Vinculo;
                    requerimento.sCargo = SessionHelper.Cargo;
                    requerimento.dtDataRequerimento = DateTime.Now;
                    requerimento.iMatricula = SessionHelper.Matricula;
                    requerimento.sSituacao = "Aberto";
                    requerimento.sTipoRequerimento = "Ferias";
                    requerimentosRepository.Inserir(requerimento);
                    TempData["Mensagem"] = "Requerimento cadastrado com sucesso";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    TempData["Mensagem"] = ex.Message;

                }
                return RedirectToAction("MeusRequerimentos");
            }
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
            Debug.Write(errors);
            return View(requerimento);
        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.FuncionariosFerias>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Minhas Férias";
}

<div class="Nome">
    <p><strong><font face="Arial" size="2"> @ViewBag.Matricula / @ViewBag.Contrato - @ViewBag.Nome</font></strong></p>
</div>
<div class="mapLocal">
    <img src="~/Content/img/sitemap.ico" width="19" height="19" /> Você está em: <i>@ViewBag.Title</i>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h5><strong>Férias</strong></h5>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <tr>
                    <th>Inicio Férias</th>
                    <th>Fim Férias</th>
                    <th>Inicio Férias Alteração</th>
                    <th>Fim Férias Alteração</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DtInicioPeriodo)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DtFimPeriodo)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DtInicioAlteracao)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DtFimAlteracao)</td>
                        <td>Editar</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sempre podes criar dois campos `[NotMapped]` (uma para a data inicial alteração e outro para a data de fim) na classe férias, para preencher com os valores que estão na classe requerimento. Para salvar os dados, no controller basta ires buscar o valor retornado da view e guardar os dados na classe requerimento

Comment: @CesarMiguel editei a pergunta com meu método para salvar, teria como ajudar em como eu pego os valores para utilizar no controller?

Comment: Você pode usar uma ViewModel

Comment: Sim, ou usar um ViewModel. Tens as duas tabelas com alguma ligação, certo? Chave estrangeira ou assim

Comment: @CesarMiguel não tenho, pois a tabela Férias é uma View no SQl, não tenho acesso a tabela em si, somente à View.

Comment: Explica lá melhor, tens duas tabelas certo? Uma com a Data Inicial e Final, e outra com a Data Inicial Alteração e Data Final Alteração. Estou certo? Como se chama cada uma destas tabelas?

Comment: @CesarMiguel, exatamente isso. Editei com os nomes de cada tabela

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade, tens a tabela férias e a requerimento?Desculpa mas é o que retenho ao ler a pergunta

Comment: Tenho a View Férias e a Tabela requerimento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode criar um único ViewModel que contempla as informações de Férias e Requerimento que você quer salvar.

ViewModel **representa um conjunto de uma ou mais Models e outros dados que serão representados em uma View** que necessita exibir determinado conjunto de informações.

Exemplo:

```
public class SeuViewModel
{
   //Todas as propriedade que você deseja utilizar na View

   //Informações de Férias...
   public int IdFerias { get; set; }
   public string DtInicioPeriodo { get; set; }
   public string DtFimPeriodo { get; set; }

   //Informações de Requerimento...
   public int IdRequerimento { get; set; }
   public string DtInicioAlteracao { get; set; }
   public string DtFimAlteracao { get; set; }
}
```

Sua View deve ser tipada conforme seu Model para que você possa acessar todas as informações:

```
@model ...SeuViewModel

<html>
    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            ...               
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

No seu Controller, sua action de Post passa a receber um objeto do seu Model:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Ferias(SeuViewModel seuViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        //Através do objeto seuViewModel, você obtem os dados informados 
        //e monta os objetos que deseja salvar.      

        ...
        var ferias = seu_repositorio.ObterFeriasPorId(seuViewModel.IdFerias);
        ferias.DataInicio = seuViewModel.DtInicioPeriodo;
        ferias.DataFim = seuViewModel.DtIFimPeriodo;

        var requerimento = seu_repositorio.ObterRequerimentoPorId(seuViewModel.IdRequerimento);
        requerimento.DataInicioAlteracao = seuViewModel.DtInicioAlteracao;
        requerimento.DataFimAlteracao = seuViewModel.DtFimAlteracao;
        ...
    } 
    ...
}
```

---

Caso seja uma "lista" de férias e requerimentos você continua tendo seu ViewModel, mas pode criar outros para serem utilizados dentro dele, exemplo:

```
public class SeuViewModel
{
   //Todas as propriedade que você deseja utilizar na View
   ...
   public IList<FeriasViewModel> { get; set; }
   public IList<RequerimentoViewModel> { get; set; }       
}

public class FeriasViewModel
{
   //Informações de Férias...
   public int IdFerias { get; set; }
   public string DtInicioPeriodo { get; set; }
   public string DtFimPeriodo { get; set; }
}

public class RequerimentoViewModel
{
   //Informações de Requerimento...
   public int IdRequerimento { get; set; }
   public string DtInicioAlteracao { get; set; }
   public string DtFimAlteracao { get; set; }
}
```

Sua View continua tipado conforme seu Model para que você possa acessar todas as informações, exemplo:

```
@model ...SeuViewModel

<html>
    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            ...      
            @foreach (var item in Model.Ferias)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.IdFerias)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DtInicioPeriodo)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DtFimPeriodo)</td>
                    <td>Editar</td>
                </tr>
            }

            ...      
            @foreach (var item in Model.Requerimentos)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.IdRequerimento)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DtInicioPeriodo)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DtFimPeriodo)</td>
                    <td>Editar</td>
                </tr>
            }
            ...       
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

No seu Controller, sua action de Post continua a receber um objeto do seu Model. Você vai receber listas de férias e requerimentos e salvá-los:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Ferias(SeuViewModel seuViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        //Através do objeto seuViewModel, você obtem os dados informados 
        //e monta os objetos que deseja salvar.      

        ...
        foreach (var item in seuViewModel.Ferias)
        {
           var ferias = seu_repositorio.ObterFeriasPorId(item.IdFerias);
           ferias.DataInicio = seuViewModel.DtInicioPeriodo;
           ferias.DataFim = seuViewModel.DtIFimPeriodo;
        }

        foreach (var item in seuViewModel.Requerimentos)
        {
           var requerimento = seu_repositorio.ObterRequerimentoPorId(seuViewModel.IdRequerimentos);
           requerimento.DataInicioAlteracao = seuViewModel.DtInicioAlteracao;
           requerimento.DataFimAlteracao = seuViewModel.DtFimAlteracao;
        ...
    } 
    ...
}
```

Comment: A resposta foi útil?